# HTML link with GET parameters: load page html and javascript before executing ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pushstate

When I paste the HTML link below in my address bar or press the browser "previous page" button my ajax GET request is executed before the html content is fully loaded resulting in my ajax returned content being displayed above my nav bar and therefore breaking my site. 
If the same request gets executed from within the site then everything is fine.
How can I make sure the page HTML and javascript loads before the ajax request is fired?

EDIT: SOLVED (answer in post below)

HTML LINK

`https://domainName/?action=listy&p=test`

JS pushstate

```
var container = document.querySelector('.lnk');
var url = "";

container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target != e.currentTarget) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.target.getAttribute('name')) {
      var data = e.target.getAttribute('name')
      url = "?action=list&p=" + data;
      history.pushState(data, null, url);
    }

  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);


window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {

  window.location.replace(url);

});
```

JQuery AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // .....
  success: function(dataBack) {
    $('.content-area').html(dataBack);
  },
});
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
$action = $_GET['action'];
$var = $_GET['p'];
switch($action) {

    case 'list' : list($var);break;


}
}
```

Comment: Can't you make an onload then call a function for the request?

Comment: Im not familiar with onload, will investigate

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but why aren't the nav bar and the content in different html elements? Then the nav bar will always be the top element and it won't matter which is loaded first.

Comment: move  every code in JS pushstate to $(document).ready(function () { });

Comment: @FarazPV tried that and it did not work, my ajax call is also inside a `$(document).ready(function ()` as you can see above

Comment: @Shilly I only have a single index.php for the entire site. `.content-area` div is inside so I really don't understand why the div container is "out of place" of the index.php HTML structure.

Comment: @Doer Can't really tell that without having that code. I'd need to know then how the HTML looks like and how the nav bar is included in it. If you just have something like `<body><? include navbar /><script>ajaxCallToLoadContent</script></body>`, then the element with the container class might get injected in the wrong order depending on where you have written it and  which function you use to add it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Note this uses the jquery library):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     Your code here...
});
```

This will wait for the page to load then run the function. I personally use this for animations but then the animations also take more time for me so I have to also include the `setTimeout` function like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
       Your code here...
}, 1000);
```

It waits a specific amount of milliseconds before executing the function.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `setTimeout()`? the `jQuery` DOM ready function `$(document).ready()`will only execute once the `DOM` has loaded

Comment: For my site I have animations that occur once the document has loaded thus the animations take a good 2 seconds of extra actual load time that's why I had to use the function. Just taking precautions he might have something else to execute once the document was loaded. @NewToJS

Comment: tried that and it did not work, my ajax call is also inside a $(document).ready(function () as you can see above. I also tried `setTimeout`

Comment: @Doer did you include the jquery library, also possibly try the timeout altough it  isn't the most efficient way.

Comment: yes please see my edited comment above. Jquery is properly loaded; I use it extensively already.

Comment: @Doer I'm sorry but sadly I can't think of anything else that may help although ill still keep the question open because it may help someone else in the future who passes by.

Comment: no worries, I managed to solve the problem partially (see updates) but still need to solve other major issues; weird stuff how things are different if the ajax is called from "inside" or "outside". Might have to open another topic

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was coming from my index.php structure;

I moved the php code in separate files and included it at the end of `index.php` instead of the top.

Now Im having other issues but the main question is resolved.

Comment: I would suggest deleting the question just in case you get some downvotes.

Comment: Can't delete :(